# auto scroll in an ultragridview for infragistics

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using an `Infragistics UltraGridView` in my program. Is it possible to set it to automatically scroll the `UltraGridView` starting at top to the bottom and then resetting it back to the top? Also the `UltraGridView` is to be set as `AutoRefresh`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply build a tight loop as this

```
foreach (UltraGridRow row in grid.Rows)
{
    row.Activate();
}
```

But it is unclear what is your purpose for this code. Your user probably will not be able to understand anything of the data while it scrolls on the grid.

Instead if your point is to set a particular row as the first one in the grid area then you should work along the line of this

```
grid.ActiveRowScrollRegion.FirstRow = grid.Rows[500];
```

(Assuming that you have more than 500 rows of course)

If you want to slow down the scrolling then you could add a Timer and in the Tick event run the Activate call. In this context you could write a class like this

```
public class SlowScroller
{
    private UltraGridRow current = null;
    private UltraGrid grd = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = null;
    public SlowScroller(UltraGrid grid)
    { 
         grd = grid; 
         t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    }

    public void Start(int interval)
    {
        t.Interval = interval;
        t.Tick += onTick;
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (t.Enabled)
           t.Stop();
    }
    private void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(current == null) 
            current = grd.Rows[0];
        else
            current = current.GetSibling(SiblingRow.Next);
        current.Activate();
    }
}
```

And call it with

```
SlowScroller ss = new SlowScroller(grid);
ss.Start(500); // Scroll every 500 milliseconds
```

Note the presence of the Stop method. This is necessary because you don't want this class to continue fire the Tick event even when you discard your form. Thus you need to call the Stop in the Form_Closing event handler

Comment: Well the purpose of the ultra grid is to let the user the data without manually scrolling. If the scroll would be a fast, is there a way I can put it on a 30 second timer?

Comment: Yes, but you need to add a Timer and run the Activate inside the Timer event. This means that you need to keep somewhere the count and reuse it

Comment: I tried using the loop but it somehow crashes the code everytime. No errors shows.

Comment: and now it doesnt crash the code but the auto scrolling does not work!! :(

Comment: No idea. I have tested it on a 8000 rows UltraGrid without any problem.

Comment: I used that code in the form load event. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Well, it is surely not a good place to start modifying the UI. The objects still don't exist as UI objects but only as class instances. Better move everything in the Forn_Shown event where everything is ready